# Prettier is not working in React Code and disappeared in status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

sorry if this question is dumb. I'm coming from Sublime Text and recently been using VSCode for my React projects. I noticed there was a Prettier status with tick or cross in the status bar but I've noticed it's not showing anymore and showing JavaScript Standard Style Instead. I've been trying to search for a way to make my Prettier works again by re-installing Prettier, install other extensions, all doesn't work at all.

The obvious sign I notice is `printWidth` option isn't working in my VSCode. I might have screwed up the configuration previously because of JS Standard but after nuked and re-installed VSCode it doesn't fix the issue at all. Any kind help or pointer is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: status bar not showing prettier]

This is my .prettierrc.json. No other overrides.

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 80
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Preference -> Settings and search for default formatter and select prettier - Code formatter

Or

In your vs code settings.json file add this   `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",`